# Fragment getting variable value from another Class

Tags: android

I'm trying to save the state of a variable with the onSaveInstanceState() of a fragment. the variable I'm trying to save is created in another class in my program, but it's always being read as 0 (initial value). I know for a fact that I am increasing the variables value. 
How can I get the actual value of the variable? This is my code:

```
public class ObjectivesActivity extends Fragment {
//Variables
ObjectivesLogic objectivesLogic = new ObjectivesLogic();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // retain this fragment
    System.out.println("savedInstanceState: " + savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore last state for checked position.
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_objectives, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (objectivesLogic.getCount()>0){
        objectivesLogic.restoreFragment();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    int save = objectivesLogic.getCount();
    System.out.println("save: "+save);
    outState.putInt("Count",save);
}


}
```

and this is where I'm creating the variable:

```
public class ObjectivesLogic extends AppCompatActivity {
//Variables
int count = 0;
View savedLinearLayoutView = null;
Context savedContext = null;
public void addObjective(Context context, View linearLayoutView) {
    savedContext = context;
    savedLinearLayoutView = linearLayoutView;
    if (count < 8) {
        EditText editText = new EditText(context);
        LinearLayout linearLayoutObjectives = (LinearLayout) linearLayoutView;
        editText.setId(R.id.edit_text_);
        linearLayoutObjectives.addView(editText);
        count++;
    }
}
public void restoreFragment(){
    for(int i=0; i<count;i++){
        EditText editText = new EditText(savedContext);
        LinearLayout linearLayoutObjectives = (LinearLayout) savedLinearLayoutView;
        editText.setId(R.id.edit_text_);
        linearLayoutObjectives.addView(editText);
        count++;
    }
}
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
}
```

getCount()always gets 0. 
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I recommend you create a Parcelable version of your "logic" object so you can save it and restore to the state parcel. Your "logic" object should _not_ inherit from any activity class at all if it isn't really an activity, you are just burning memory for no real reason that way. Don't set id's for programmatically created views, it makes little sense as id's are only used to bridge the XML-Code gap. Try not to hold on to a Context instance as it can lead to a very serious memory leak.

Comment: Always happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Two problems I've seen in your codes that should be resolved.

- `ObjectivesLogic` class is extending `Activity` class, which as appears it doesn't need. Also, you should never instantiate a class extending `Activity` manually, this should be done by Android framework not you.
- You're only saving that variable: `outState.putInt("Count",save);`. I couldn't see any thing about restoring it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` before `outState.putInt("Count",save);`

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    int save = objectivesLogic.getCount();
    System.out.println("save: "+save);
    outState.putInt("Count",save);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}
```

Comment: This isn't really the reason. You can call ``super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);`` at any time (or not at all - not recommended) and saving/restoring from a parcel object will work anyway.

Comment: @Machinarius i was looking at [SaveState](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState) ... what's the recommended way then ? (genuinely curious)

Comment: Indeed you should call ``super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);`` but it's really optional AFAIK, If you don't call it then your UI state will never be restored and new activities will start from scratch but it shouldn't lead into an error.

Comment: That's exactly what the answer above says. I downvote this one not because it's wrong but because the proposed solution does not solve the root problem really.

Comment: Well he's not getting an error, the count variable is never restored with the value he think he has put in.  I assumed he restored it in   `if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore last state for checked position.
    }`  but yes i concur with your comment to op that the code should be better organized.